# Ubuntu Minimal in the new Intel NUC Haswell

Tags: networking, 13.10, ubuntu-minimal

I have one the of the new Haswell NUCs that just came out - D34010WYK.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23089&lang=eng&OSVersion=OS%20Independent&DownloadType=Documentation),

I tried to load ubuntu minimal 13.10 x64 from the mini.iso and it cannot properly detect a network during install - my guess is a driver issue.  Tried 12.04 lts and it doesnt even see the NIC at all. Is there anything I could do to get one of the current versions to see the network properly?

I did try the latest trusty nightly desktop and it did install without issue.  Is there a minimal version of that?

Thanks
Ernie

Answer (score 1):

The ethernet configuration for 13.10 never worked for me during the installation. The wireless card does work (if you installed one). If you are able to reach a terminal after installation, you can setup the NIC yourself by editing

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Add to the end,

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet dhcp
```

Save, then start the new NIC with

```
sudo ifup em1
```

Use `ifconfig` to confirm.

On Ubuntu 12.04, it should be called eth0 instead of em1. If you are not sure, use

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

and you can see what your NICs are called.

Specs:
Intel NUC DC3217IYE

Works on:
Ubuntu Server 12.04.2
Ubuntu Server 13.10 
Ubuntu Minimal 13.10